# Google maps code getting forced closed

Tags: android, google-maps

The following source code is not getting executed... I am learning how to handle google maps.. Please help

this is my source code::

```
package com.example.maptest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.google.android.maps.*;


public class MainActivity extends MapActivity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    LocationManager locationManager =
            (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Location location = null;

    double lat = location.getLatitude() * 100000;
    double longi = location.getLongitude() * 100000;


    LocationProvider provider =
            locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

This is the XML file

```
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:apiKey="0GH71P-8YZB_XmnfIDs_-NOCtdlku2nwKABE61Q"
             />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My AndroidManifest is::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maptest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maptest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

I am really getting confused about why it is not starting...Please help

```
03-17 08:34:05.215: W/dalvikvm(2380): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maptest/com.example.maptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.maptest.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.maptest-2.apk 
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:210)
```

Comment: A stack trace would help.

Comment: @pratik Ghate Try my solution.

Comment: @pratik Ghate You should use google maps api v2.

Comment: @meh I am not able to get the API key for V2

Answer (score 2):

```
Location location = null;

double lat = location.getLatitude() * 100000;
double longi = location.getLongitude() * 100000;
```

You're calling methods on a null reference, no wonder your application crashes. You should initialize the `location` variable somehow, for example calling `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Initialising location variable to LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()

Comment: @pratikGhate, I wasn't giving you the exact code you should use, I thought you would get the idea. Change it to locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER).

Comment: @pratikGhate, What else can I help you with?

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize the location. So I guess you getting NPE

```
Location location = getGPSLocation(this);
if(location != null) {
   double lat = location.getLatitude() * 100000;
   double longi = location.getLongitude() * 100000;
}
```

Edit:

```
private Location getGPSLocation(Context context) {
    try {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria cr = new Criteria();
        cr.setCostAllowed(true);
        cr.setAccuracy(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        cr.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(cr, true);
        if(provider == null)
            provider = lm.getBestProvider(cr, false);
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("App", "Exception while fetch GPS at: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
```

and Add this permission AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: @pratikGhate I think your NPE exception has solved earlier you did not initialize the location. any way please post the logcat.

Comment: 03-17 08:34:05.215: W/dalvikvm(2380): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maptest/com.example.maptest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.maptest.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.maptest-2.apk
03-17 08:34:05.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2380):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:210)

Comment: Edit you question and post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I only solved library error.. basic error still remains the same

Comment: @pratikGhate Try to add Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER); and make sure you have internet connection in device.

Comment: @pratikGhate Try it again it might help you. I have edited my answer and start the internet in your mobile.

Comment: @pratikGhate What issue you have please explain me again.

Comment: In this basic app i am just trying to show the map on emulator... But the application is getting forced closed

Comment: @pratikGhate Check on use wireless network in settings and have internet connection and test it on device. because you will not get gps location in emulator.

Comment: I've a working connection for emulator..Can you give me any code to learn basics of maps which I could refer??

Comment: I don't have but if run the application which need current location. its not possible to test in emulator because it will always give you 0,0 latitude and longitude or either fix if fixed it geo command.

Comment: @pratikGhate Only one option let me check give your teamviewer id. I can't do more than that.